# Laplace transform of piecewise function - making it to become heaviside unitstep function

Tags: laplace-transform, laplace-method

The piecewise function of $f(t)$ is as follows-

$f(t) = t , 0\le t < 1 $

$f(t) = 2-t , 1\le t \le 2$

$f(t) = 0 ,  t>2$

I made a quick sketch - [image]

now, I need help on making this into a formula f(t) = something.

I am not too sure on this shape of the graph. The function is ‘ON’ from 0 to 2. 
If I am not wrong, it is called the heaviside unitstep function

I need to get a function of f(t) before I can apply the laplace transform of second shifting to get the answer for Laplace transform of that function.. thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Heaviside 's function..

$$f(t)=t-tH(t-1)+(2-t)(H(t-1)-H(t-2))+0H(t-2)$$
$$f(t)=t-tH(t-1)+(2-t)(H(t-1)-H(t-2))$$
$$f(t)=t+(2-2t)H(t-1)-(2-t)H(t-2))$$
$$f(t)=t+2(1-t)H(t-1)-(2-t)H(t-2))$$
$$f(t)=t-2(t-1)H(t-1)+(t-2)H(t-2))$$

Then take the Lpalace transform

Note that :
$$\mathcal{L}(f(t-c)H(t-c))=e^{-cs}F(s)$$
Therefore we have :
$$\boxed {F(s)=\frac 1{s^2}-2\frac {e^{-s}}{s^2} +\frac {e^{-2s}}{s^2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to calculate the laplace transform from the definition:
$$F(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-st}\mathrm{d}t$$
$$F(s)=\int_{0}^{1}te^{-st}\mathrm{d}t+\int_{1}^{2}(2-t)e^{-st}\mathrm{d}t$$

Comment: I’ve been thought to form the heaviside function first and need to use that in practices and exam, is there a way to that ? I am not too sure of that.

Comment: @user185692 Check Ian's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about Heaviside, just break it into two integrals and evaluate it.

Botond has it right. $$ F(s)=\int_{0}^{1}te^{-st}\mathrm{d}t+\int_{1}^{2}(2-t)e^{-st}\mathrm{d}t$$

Now you have to do integration by parts which I hope you still remember from your calculus class.

Comment: I’ve been thought to form the heaviside function first and need to use that in practices and exam, is there a way to that ? I’m not too sure of that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the step function then you take a case which applies on $(a,b)$ and multiply it by $H(t-a)-H(t-b)$ (note the order, and use the convention $H(t-\infty)=0$) and then sum over cases. This is useful because it matches the form used for Laplace transform tables.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$ t(H(0)-H(1)) + (2-t)(H(1)-H(2)) =tH(0)-2(t-1)H(1)+(t-2)H(2)$$

You should be able to finish it.